# Cortest.mat converting to class "psych,sim"

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, pearson

I've been using the `psych` package to compare two correlation matrices using the function `cortest`.

Now I want to try the `cortest.mat` and `cortest.jennrich` function which require an object of the class `phych`and `sim`. I have tried converting mi correlation matrices with `sim.structure` which results in an object of such classes but I get an error when running either function.

Here is what I've tried using Random numbers:

```
Random<-cor(matrix(rnorm(400, 0, .25), nrow=(20), ncol=(20)))
SimRandom<-sim.structure(Random)
class(SimRandom)
cortest.jennrich(SimRandom,SimRandom,n1=400, n2=400)
```

Yields the following:

> Error in if (dim(R1)[1] != p) { : argument is of length zero

I sure I'm doing it wrong 'cause of the error message and 'cause the values in Random and SimRandom are not exactly the same.

Which is the correct way to translate a correlation matrix to a type -phych, sim- to use as input for running cortest.mat?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Short explanation on what I want to do. Using Random numbers serves just as an example. The actual correlation matrices to compare are done as follows. I have a huge list of files each composed of 100 observations for a specific genetic location. These files can be grouped into say 20 files based on known genetic relationships, thus I use those groups of files, load them into a matrix as columns and calculate cor(). That gives a correlation matrix. As a control I load random files and treat them the same way. This matrix contains real data, but the grouping is done randomly. In the end I have two correlation matrices 1-That contains the correlations of pre-selected files and 2- that contains the correlations between randomly loaded files. Both matrices are the same size.

What I would like to do is to compare the two correlation matrices to have an idea whether the grouping has an influence on the correlation values observed.

Sorry for not explaining this earlier, I wanted to avoid the long explanation and keep the question simple.

Comment: for starters your objects are misspelled...although thats a transcription issue. It always helps to run the code you paste on SO first in your console to make sure you know what you're actually pasting.

Comment: It would also help to provide us with an idea of what you're trying to do...ultimately. I already showed you how to create a random matrix and run it using ``cortest``. Do you have raw data you're working with that you converted into a matrix?

Comment: You mean SinRandom against SimRandom? Sorry about that I did a last minute change here. In the original code everything was SinRandom. I'll edit the post.

Comment: I would recommend following the tutorial found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/vignettes/overview.pdf). It has all the info you need, practice datasets, the logic behind the functions, etc.

Comment: if you post the original raw data, it'll be easier to help. ``cortest`` allows you to work with raw data

Comment: There's nothing special about the real data and the random numbers in the code reproduce the error.